# How can I get more than two answers from a boolean variable?

Tags: java, class

I need to create a class called Point, this Object will have parameters of X and Y. Then I had to make a method which checks if that point is above another point, so I did that:

```
public boolean isAbove(Point1 other) {
    if(other.getY() > _y) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

And the next method I had to do called "isUnder", but in this method I must only use the "isAbove" method I've created. This is the "isUnder" method I've created:

```
public boolean isUnder(Point1 other) {
    return !isAbove(other);
}
```

How can I know if the point aren't at the same "height"? With the methods I created the only results I get are TRUE, FALSE, but if the points are the same "height" I should get FALSE,FALSE on both methods.

Comment: then you should understand why this: return !isAbove(this); is wrong

Comment: I've changed "this" to "other", but it isn't the issue... I still get False, True

Comment: Boolean variables have only 2 possible values: true and false.  True is the inverse of false, and vice versa.  So the inverse of `isAbove()` when `isAbove()` is false, is going to be true, because the inverse of false is true.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong that's what I told my teacher, but he said that this is a riddle, and there's a trick which will get it right... idk

Answer (score 0):

```
class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public PointYPosition getYPosition(Point otherPoint) {
        if (otherPoint.y > y) return PointYPosition.ABOVE;
        if (otherPoint.y < y) return PointYPosition.UNDER;

        return PointYPosition.EQUALS;
    }
}

enum PointYPosition {
    ABOVE,
    UNDER,
    EQUALS
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I must use only the "isAbove" method, this is part of the exercise, I could easily solve it with another "if" argument to check that both Ys aren't equal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following implementation, however I must say if you need to ***only*** use the other method, there is no way

```java
public boolean isUnder(Point1 other) {
    return !isAbove(other) && other.getY() != _y;
}
```

That way you can even have a third method `isEqual`

```java
public boolean isEqual(Point1 other) {
    return !isAbove(other) && !isUnder(other);
}
```

---

That being said here is how I would implement this myself

```java
public boolean isAbove(Point1 other) {
    return other.getY() < _y;
}

public boolean isUnder(Point1 other) {
    return other.getY() > _y;
}

public boolean isOnTheSameHeight(Point1 other) {
    return !isAbove(other) && !isUnder(other);
}

public boolean isAboveOrOnTheSameHeight(Point1 other) {
    return isAbove(other) || isOnTheSameHeight(other);
}

// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public int compareTo(Point otherPoint) {
    return Integer.compare(_y, otherPoint.getY());
}
```

The `Integer.compare(x, y)` returns -1 if x is less than y, returns 0 if they're equal, and returns 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I found a post from 7 years ago with the exact same question, someone solved it there

```
return other.isAbove(this);
```

Thank you all very much!